# Displaying a form (simple php file) in a modal box?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, modal-dialog

I currently load a form in a new popup window (urgh!) and when you submit this, it'll close the popup window, and open yet another popup with the results from your form submition.

Needless to say this was a pretty terrible idea and I'd like to put it right. Can anyone please recommend a fairly simple way to display my form (popup.php) in a modal box, and when you submit that, it will load another page in the same window (report.php)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use jQueryUI to create a dialog box

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Wow, it even has a 'modal form' option! (although the example doesn't work) - thank you!